# Model for dynamic plate deformation

Tags: mechanical-engineering, vibration, elastic-modulus, deformation

I would like  to gather ideas to model the dynamic behaviour of a plate with variable thickness. The assumption are:

- Small deformations.
- The plate is all made of the same material with variable thickness.
- Boundary condition can be: free edge or fixed force profile.

My goal is to have a model as simple as possible and solve it with a Matlab script. The desired input are plate physical properties and boundary conditions. The desired output is the dynamics of each point of the plate.

The main ideas I am pursuing right now are:

- Write the differential equation and solve using finite differences.
- Simplify the whole model with equivalent springs and point masses.

Comment: If you qualify for a student license (to keep the cost down), don't waste your time writing your own code - get the Partial Differential Equations toolbox instead.

Comment: Or you might find something in Octave for free. Octave is made to be very similar to MATLAB but open source.

Comment: Another option is to use python. But my question is not really about the coding part. What I am seeking are ideas on how to treat / discretize / sinplify the system in an effective way.